# Change all boolean parameters of an Animator in Unity

Tags: unity, animation

How can I change all boolean parameters of an animator to `false`?

Here is a solution which I found:

```
foreach (AnimatorControllerParameter parameter in playerAnimator.parameters)
{
    playerAnimator.SetBool(parameter.name, false);
}
```

The problem with this solution is that I will get a warning in console if my parameter in `Animator` is not a boolean. I would not like to be getting that. So, I need somehow to being able to take only parameters of type boolean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a check:

```
foreach (AnimatorControllerParameter parameter in playerAnimator.parameters) {
    if (parameter.type == AnimatorControllerParameterType.Bool)
        playerAnimator.SetBool(parameter.name, false);
}
```

Comment: Where did you get such knowledge?

Comment: You can find the info about the `AnimatorControllerParameter` class in the Unity docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimatorControllerParameter.html - please don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem. :)